# Identification of the cell membrane in IF image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, bitmap

I'm struggling against a very difficult problem.

I've some images (immunofulorescence images) which represent some proteins and I need to identify the "external" membrane of these proteins. 
The problem is shown in the images below. 
The external membrane is represented by the red path in the image B and I have to identify it (the external membrane is not uniform but it has different thicknesses along the path)

[image]

I can't use a threshold because I've to include ALL the pixels inside the membrane (the threshold creates holes instead because some pixels inside the membrane have the same values of other pixels outside the membrane).

I've tried to use the Canny's algorithm and a lot of edge detection algorithms but the results are not acceptable; they are not able to identify the membrane even if I try on a small part.

I've tried another way.

I've identified the external path using marching square.
For each two points of the marching square I've find a segment normal two the segment defined by these two points. 
I've analyzed the profile along these "normal" segments and for each profile I have chosen two points that contains the membrane (as in figure C).
The result is not good because I can't cover all the membrane and it's not easy to anlyze the profile to decide where the membrane starts and ends.
This is what I obtain:
[image]
Can anyone suggest an algorithm or some idea to deal this problem?

Other similar images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Will you always have a coloured image (the membrane) over a black background?

Comment: No, unfortunately the background is not black but dark green and it's not uniform.

Comment: Did you look into OpenCV? It does provide an [implementation](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/void-canny-inputarray-image-outputarray.html#.VSUIzfmUdHM) of the Canny algorithm. Maybe you could try and sharpen the image before processing?

Comment: I didn't use OpenCv. I've tryed with this code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93642/Canny-Edge-Detection-in-C. What do you mean with "sharpen" the image? I've tryed to interpolate the marching square with a curve to avoid peaks but the result is too much rough...

Comment: Hi Martina, had some time to play around. I managed to reproduce something along the lines you are asking. You should be in a position to fine tune the code to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

For your example image, Gimp's fuzzy select tools seems to find the outside of the protein quite well (see below -- but maybe that's the case because it's scaled down already? Can you post original image samples?). So I'd try something like the following

1. Use a variation of [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) to find the outer border
2. For two points next to each other on the outer border, determine the normal and march it until values stop going up, then until values stop going down.

[image: Gimp Fuzzy Select]

Comment: Hi Stefan, I can't post any images because I have a reputation under 10. I've tryed Gimp with the original image but the result is not what I expect. Moreover the background of my image is not black and it is not uniform so If I use something like flood fill algorithm I need to use a threshold too. For now I've only find the outer border with marching square but it's very inaccurate and in some points includes the background. Thank you

Comment: Would it be ok to downscale the image a bit, getting rid of some noise? Maybe that's why fuzzy select worked fine? P.S. Your reputation seems to be above 10 now :)

Comment: I did it but the tool find the outer border and something inside...I've posted some other images!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? This is by no means an answer, but I cannot post everything as a comment.

This code is in C++, and to run it you will need to install OpenCV, which if you have visual studio, can be done through NuGet.

The code below is something I got from [here](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/find-contour.html#.VSUOT_mUdHM).

```
int main()
{
    Mat image;
    image = imread("path to image", 1);
    Mat original = image.clone();
    //Sharpen the image. This should ease edge detection. The the higher the second value, the sharper the image will be.
    cv::addWeighted(image, 20.0, image, -0.5, 0, image);
    //Blur the image slightly. This should handle internal edges. The higher the last value will be, the more blurred the image will be.
    cv::GaussianBlur(image, image, cv::Size(0, 0), 2);
    namedWindow("Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Canny(gray, gray, 100, 200, 3);
    /// Find contours   
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    RNG rng(12345);
    findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    /// Draw contours
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(gray.size(), CV_8UC3);
    Scalar color = Scalar(0, 0, 255);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {       
        drawContours(original, contours, i, color, 2, 2, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }

    imshow("Result window", original);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Given the below:

[image: Source Image]

Yields

[image: Resultant Image]

Comment: The result seems good but I'm having some difficulties to write this code in c# language to test it on others images. I'm using emgu.

Comment: @Martina: Can you please say what errors you are experiencing? This code could be expanded to try out a series of files in a particular folder and save them somewhere if that would help.

Comment: I'm not able to translate the function  cv::GaussianBlur(image, image, cv::Size(0, 0), 2); into c#. I'm using GpuInvoke.GaussianBlur(...) but I'm not sure about the parameter to use. I'm completely new to OpenCv and Emgu

Comment: @Martina: Could you try something like so: `CvInvoke.cvSmooth(src, dst, SMOOTH_TYPE.CV_GAUSSIAN, 13, 13, 1.5, 0);`.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not able to write in c# vector<Vec4i> hierarchy; RNG rng(12345); Scalar color = Scalar(0, 0, 255) and CV_BGR2GRAY

Comment: @Martina: Please refer to [this](https://lasithapetthawadu.wordpress.com/2014/06/14/basic-contour-extraction-of-an-image-using-c-and-emgucv/) link, more specifically look at the FindContours.cs section./